# Parent <ul> overriding its childs styling

Tags: css, xhtml, html-lists

This is my markup:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Articles</a>
            <ul class="inside-ul">
                <li><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Article 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I apply styling to the parent `<ul>` like this:

```
#nav ul {
    something;
}

#nav ul li {
    something;
}

#nav ul li a {
    something;
}
```

And I apply styling to the child `<ul>` like this:

```
.inside-ul {
    something;
}

.inside-ul li {
    something;
}

.inside-ul li a {
    something;
}
```

But the problem is, the child `<ul>` (.inside-ul) doesn't change at all, it's like it inherits everything from its parent. I have tried using `!important` in my CSS file but it still remains the same.

Here is an image of what's happening:

http://i47.tinypic.com/w1brkw.jpg

I hope I've explained myself clearly, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
#nav ul {
    something;
}
```

to

```
#nav > ul {
    something;
}
```

That way the CSS is only applied to the child UL of #nav and not the sub UL.

Comment: Difference between descendents and children...   See http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/document_child.htm and http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/document_descendant.htm for a visual comparison.  +1

Comment: Child selectors don't work in IE6 - in case you need to support that browser

Comment: @michael Very simple explanations. I like it.

@matt You are very welcome

Comment: I didn't know about using > in css!!!  I've been playing around with the styles for a list (same as the poster's question) for a couple hours - glad I found this! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
.inside-ul {
    something;
}

.inside-ul li {
    something;
}

.inside-ul li a {
    something;
}
```

to this:

```
#nav ul.inside-ul {
    something;
}

#nav ul.inside-ul li {
    something;
}

#nav ul.inside-ul li a {
    something;
}
```

More specific rules (in this case rules which apply to an id (#nav) have precedence over simpler rules.

Answer (score 1):

It is a [CSS specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) issue.

Id's have a value of 100 while classes have a value of 10 and each element name has a value of 1.

So `#nav ul` = 101
while `.inside_ul` = 10

If two selectors apply to the same element, the one with higher specificity wins.

So the #nav ul styles will take precedence. You will need to use

```
#nav ul.inside_ul
```

which has a specificity of 111.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure that the most important ones come last? The `.inside-ul` should come after the `#nav ul` in the CSS file.